# How can I Get Sku In Products Ordered Reports

Tags: magento-1.9, reports, sku

I want display sku at products ordered reports page, how can i get sku ?

[image]

Comment: u want sku column on grid

Comment: yes... found solution,, below

Comment: it not proper way to add sku you want extend to core block you own module

Comment: @ArshadMuhammad please don't confuse people. Your method is considered as good practice.

Comment: thanks @GopalPatel i don't confuse people just to share my knowledge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

open `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Report\Product\Sold\Grid.php` and put the below code in `_prepareColumns()` function

You can **move** `Grid.php` in your **local folder** as well or **can override it in custom module**.

```
$this->addColumn('sku', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Sku'),
    'index'     =>'sku'
));
```

Comment: better to avoid edits on core files.

Comment: this code is working only for simple products for me, do you have option for configurable?

Answer (score 6):

You should rewrite magento core block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Product_Sold_Grid`, here is the solution:

```
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <report_product_sold_grid>Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid</report_product_sold_grid>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

and extend in your moduel:

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Product_Sold_Grid
{

    public function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('sku', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Sku'),
            'index' => 'sku'
        ));
        parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

Comment: But its working

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/n5na90K.png

Comment: Does right what i did...

Comment: @JeevaRathinam yes it is right. His point is to override the grid in custom module which is good practice

Comment: u can override hole methode you own function just comment parent::_prepareColumns();

Comment: public function _prepareColumns()
 {
        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Name'),
            'index'     =>'order_items_name'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('sku', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Sku'),
            'index'     =>'sku'
        ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
 }

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create an extension for this functionality or just use mine

[Magento 1.x Simple Products Report Extension](https://github.com/harout-itology/Simpleproductsreport)